# Julia: Simple Manual Matrix Input

Tags: matrix, julia

Could someone please demonstrate how to input a matrix manual in Julia?

Code might act like like:

```
pseudo>(9 3 2, 3 2 1)

9 3 2
3 2 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical MATLAB syntax.

```
julia> [9 3 2; 3 2 1]
2x3 Array{Int64,2}:
9  3  2
3  2  1
```